# Add list or numpy array as column to a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

How can i add a list or a numpy array as a column to a Dask dataframe? When i try with the regular pandas syntax `df['x']=x` it gives me a `TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type list` error.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a pandas series:

```py
df["new_col"] = pd.Series(my_list, index=index_matching_df_index)
```

The issue is that the index is extremely important so dask can understand how to partition the data. The size of each partition in a dask dataframe is not always known, so you cannot assign by position.

Comment: Yep, i actually solved the issue by just casting the list into a dask array, and then worked flawless, but i think i'm gonna rollback on switchnig from pandas to dask.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it just casting the list into a dask array with `dask.array.from_array()`, which i think it's the most direct way.

Comment: this works if you know the exact locations of the dask dataframe partitions. but you couldn't use this if you had previously changed the partitions, e.g. `df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas({'A': np.random.random(size=1000)}); df = df[df.A > 0.3];`. Now you can't assign based on index directly. much of the dask.dataframe design is structured around working with unknown partition sizes.